# How to ensure a timeout per each Future in an iterator of concurrent.futures?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, timeout, concurrent.futures

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-concurrent.futures) around timeouts for `concurrent.futures` is very challenging to understand. In a simple case, I'd like to use a `ProcessPoolExecutor` by calling `.submit` in a loop that scans through a list of job functions. I want each of these `Future` objects to have an associated timeout of 10 minutes, but otherwise for them to complete asynchronously.

My first approach was to try to use the [`as_completed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.as_completed) function, which produces an iterator of the Future objects and only yields the next when one has completed. `as_completed` accepts a `timeout` parameter but the documentation says this timeout is relative to the first moment when `as_completed` is called, and not necessarily the lifetime of any `Future` object itself.

E.g. suppose the `ProcessPoolExecutor` only has 3 worker processes but the list of `Future` objects contains 10 items. 7 of the items may sit in an unprocessed state for up to 10 minutes while the first 3 items are processed. Shortly thereafter, the timeout from `as_completed` will be tripped resulting in a failure, even though each individual `Future` may have met the 10 minute limit on its own.

Note that the same limitations that apply for `as_completed` will also apply for [`wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.wait) and `wait` is harder to use for this use case because of the limited return options it supports.

My next thought was to use the [`timeout` parameter that `future.result` allows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.result) and call `f.result(timeout=600)` for each `f` (Future) in my list of futures. However, there is not really a way to set this timeout without actually demanding the result in a blocking way. If you iterate the list of futures and call `f.result(...)`, this call blocks for the specified timeout.

On the other hand, you also cannot combine `f.result` with `as_completed` either, in a naive but seemingly correct way like

```
[f.result(timeout=600) for f in as_completed(futures_list)]
```

... because the iteration of `as_completed` is deceptively waiting asynchronously as the futures complete and only returning them to have `.result` called *after* they have already completed.

Given this, what is the right pattern to produce a list of `Future`s where each one has its own individual timeout and then wait on them asynchronously to finish?

Comment: So far it seems there is no way to achieve this. As a workaround I plan to segment my list of job functions into chunks of the same size as the number of workers of the process pool. Then I will only convert them to futures via `submit` and call `as_completed` on chunks where I can guarantee that the timeout should apply across all of the futures at once. This is a significant concession though, to have to do my own batching because the API of concurrent.futures doesn't support what may perhaps be the second most critical use case beyond handling one Future in isolation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears there is no way to supply a per-Future timeout in this kind of asynchronous context. The available API functions `wait` and `as_completed` take the easier road by supporting a global timeout across all tasks in a iterable of `Future` objects and do not attempt to measure the time from when the `Future` first starts to be actively in a state of being processed.

I chose a workaround of separating my task list into a set of chunks and using `as_completed` for each chunk. The chunk size is set to be the same as the number of workers that my `ProcessPoolExecutor` is configured to use, so that I can be somewhat sure the "global" timeout of `as_completed` is secretly functioning as a per-Future timeout since all of the tasks are actively processed right away. The downside is somewhat less utilization because the process pool is not free to grab the next Future task when tasks finish early; it has to wait for the entire next batch of tasks. For me this is OK but it is a significant usability deficiency of `concurrent.futures` that I must choose.

Here is some example code. Suppose that `my_task_list` already contains functions with some or all required arguments bound via `functools.partial` or other means. You could modify this so that arguments are supplied in a separate iterable of tuples or dicts and passed into `submit` as needed.

```
my_task_list = #... define your list of task functions
num_workers = #... set number of workers
my_timeout = #... define your timeout
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_workers) as pool:
    all_results = []
    for chunk_start in range(0, len(my_task_list), num_workers):
        chunk = my_task_list[chunk_start:chunk_start + num_workers]
        # could extract parameters to pass for this task chunk here.
        futures = [pool.submit(task) for task in chunk]
        all_results += [
            f.result() for f in as_completed(futures, timeout=my_timeout)
        ]
    return all_results
```

Note that if you choose `num_workers` higher than the number of processors available to the `ProcessPoolExecutor`, you'll end up with more tasks than processors within a given chunk and return to the situation where the timeout of `as_completed` won't correctly apply to the runtime of each task, likely leading to the same kind of timeout errors as if just using `as_completed` or `wait` on the overall task list with no chunking.